# Show a textbox if there is only one value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<div class="span3">  
    <select name="u_home_country" data-validation-required-message="Enter your home country" class="form-control" required id="user_home_country">                             
    <?php foreach ($countryOptionshome as $key => $countryName) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $countryName ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

How do i show a input textbox if there is only one value in the array. I am using codeigniter

EDIT :

I am getting the array values `countryOptionshome` from a controller so can't use count

```
 foreach ($jsonhome as $queryhome) {
                foreach ($queryhome['results']['place'] as $placeshome) {

                    if (!empty($placeshome['country']['content'])) {
                        $aData['countryOptionshome'][] = $placeshome['country']['content'];
                    }
                    if (!empty($placeshome['admin1']['content'])) {
                        $aData['stateOptionshome'][] = $placeshome['admin1']['content'];
                    }
                    if (!empty($placeshome['admin2']['content'])) {
                        $aData['cityOptionshome'][] = $placeshome['admin2']['content'];
                    }
                }
            }


            $this->load->view('header_register');
            $this->load->view('body_complete_register', $aData);
            $this->load->view('footer_register');
```

Comment: `if (sizeof() == 1)`?

Comment: you get values from AJAX you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try something like (to check for just one value in the array and create a textbox input:

```
<?php

if(count($countryOptionshome) == 1)     //or sizeof() which is an alias for count  
       echo form_input('inputName', 'inputValue');
 else {
      //do other stuff
 }

?>
```

This more related to how should work your code, but seems you're not always setting the array named `$countryOptionshome`  if can or can't be setted check in the view with the `isset()` function before trying to access it with `count()`

```
if (isset($countryOptionshome)) {
  //do your thing with the array

   if(count($countryOptionshome) == 1)     //or sizeof() which is an alias for count  
       echo form_input('inputName', 'inputValue');
   else {
      //do other stuff
 }
}
```

If can debug do it, if don't comment this lines:

```
    /*$this->load->view('header_register');
    $this->load->view('body_complete_register', $aData);
    $this->load->view('footer_register');*/
```

And after the comment add the below line and please post/check the output:

```
  echo var_dump($aData);
```

If needs more control for the input's attributes see the form_helper doc:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Hi i am getting array values from controller on a button click

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: countryOptionshome

Filename: views/body_complete_register.php

Line Number: 96

Comment: What do you mean with "on a button click" ? onclick event with JavaScript ? or are you submiting a form to a controller that load the view with the code you posted?.

Comment: i am loading a view from a controller

Comment: Please post at least the code where you are loading the view (the one where you're trying to show the input-text) I think you're having troubles sending the array to the view, I mean 1.- you aren't sending the array to the view or 2.- you're not accessing properly to the array from the view.

Comment: Seems you're not setting the array in the controller,debug your controller code, make sure you're setting the "countryOptionshome" you can check with the isset() function.

Comment: Hi the controller is not called on page load but a href click that is why i am getting the issue

Comment: @vini Mmm I don't think that's an issue, besides the form's action attribute, using links to call methods from controllers is the way to go,seems more like you're not setting always the "countryOptionshome" (neither the other arrays) in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<div class="span3">  
   <?php if(count($countryOptionshome) <= 1)
        echo '<input type="text" name="something" >';
   else { ?>
    <select name="u_home_country" data-validation-required-message="Enter your home country" class="form-control" required id="user_home_country">                             
    <?php 
        foreach ($countryOptionshome as $key => $countryName) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $countryName ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What if i want o show one array value in the input field?

Comment: This wont work as i am getting the array values from controller

Comment: If you don't provide more info about the controller and the view, we can't help you.